# Spring JPA to "release" an Entity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Thanks for reading this in advance.

I use Spring data JPA to query data from DB:

`UserProfile userProfile = userProfileRepository.findByCustomerID(id);`

After the data returned I want to change some value to some field:

`userProfile.setRemark("some remark");`

However, I notice that Spring will automatically update the database of this record which I don't want, as this field is just a temp value for some further processing.

May I know how can I let Spring data JPA to kinda "ignore" or "drop" this entity from the managed pool? I found someone said to use:

`entityManager.clear();`

And tested it definitely will not update the database if this one is called. But I am not sure if this is the correct way to do so, does `entityManager.clear();` will clear other managed entities as well?

Many thanks.

Comment: Also ```entityManager.detach(Object); ``` seems also can be used. I am not sure which one is better.

Comment: If it isn't part of your entity, then why is it even on the entity? If you really want to do this (which I think you shouldn't) and the field doesn't belong in the database you should mark it `@Transient`.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum , the field is belong to the entity but i just don't want to update the database.

Comment: Then don't set it on the entity...

Comment: I think you should use dozer with that you can transfer your entity object into DTO(data transfer) object and then you need to change or update remark directly into dto object which will not impact to the database.